# Due to magento cache some attribute blocks are not showing on homepage

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-attributes

I have made some attribute so that client can select his desired products to show on homepage.

For each attribute i have one block and every one is allowed already in admin.

There are 10 rows of products. But some rows are showing and some are not due to magento cache. When i disable cache, everything shows.

What may be the cause? I tried deleting all cache many times.

Comment: Have you try reindexing ?

Comment: how do you render the blocks in the homepage?

Comment: However i have turned off CDN and everything is working. But very strange and can't describe about the amazing behaviour of magento with cloudflare cdn.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `cache_lifetime` to null Below is the example how you can disable cache_lifetime for one block , just `cache_lifetime=> null` and that block not cache

http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-block-caching/